# How to retrieve content block in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, content-builder, marketingcloudapi

I'm trying to retrieve a content block for a script in ssjs. I tried already several functions but it seems not working.
The scope is with a script to retrieve a content from a content area and push this information in a email.

```
%%[/*SET @html = ContentBlockByKey("f716faaa-8170-4940-b1af-c84ee1f5862a")*/]%%

<script runat=server language=javascript>
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.5");
/************************ UTILITY FUNCTIONS *****************************************/
function getAccessToken(){
var request = new Script.Util.HttpRequest('https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken');
request.method = "POST";
request.contentType = 'application/json';
request.postData = '{ "clientId": "'+ clientID + '", "clientSecret" : "' + clientSECRET + '"}';

response = request.send();

var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(''+response.content);

if (!json.accessToken) {
    exit();
}
return json.accessToken;
}  
   function updateDebugLog(textToAdd, activateDEBUG, eraseContentBlock){
// Retrieving old content
if(Boolean(activateDEBUG) && activateDEBUG){
    var request = new Script.Util.HttpRequest('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/' + debugId + '?access_token=' + jsonACCESSTOKEN);
    request.method = "GET";
    request.contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    response = request.send();
    // adding new content and updating
    var existingBody = '';
    if(eraseContentBlock != true ) existingBody = Platform.Function.ParseJSON('' + response.content).content + "<br/>";
    var newContent = existingBody + textToAdd ;
    request.method = "PATCH";
    request.postData = '{ "content": "' + newContent + '" }';
    response = request.send();
}
}   
function updateEmail(newContent){
// Retrieving old content
    var request = new Script.Util.HttpRequest('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets/' + emailid + '?access_token=' + jsonACCESSTOKEN);
    request.method = "GET";
    request.contentType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    response = request.send();
    // adding new content and updating
    var existingBody = '';
    request.method = "PATCH";
    request.postData = '{ "content": "' + newContent + '" }';
    response = request.send();
}
/************* STARTING EXECUTION **********************/
var response;
var clientID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
var clientSECRET = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY';
var jsonACCESSTOKEN = getAccessToken();
// Debug Content Area
var debugId = 383362;
var emailid = 397405;
var startDEBUG = true;
var eraseDEBUGeveryTime = false;
//var newCountent = Platform.Function.ContentBlockByKey("f716faaa-8170-4940-b1af-c84ee1f5862a")
//var newContent = Variable.GetValue('@html');
var newContent = ('THIS WAS MODIFIED');
// Configuration Values
var categoryId= 1433833;
updateDebugLog("Execution started at " + DateTime.SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()), true, true);
updateEmail(newContent);
updateDebugLog("Execution finished at " + DateTime.SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()), true, false);
</script>
THE EMAIL IS NOW UPDATED
```

This is the code I used. By writing directly the text, the script works fine, but if I try to get any HTML Code it will not work anymore.
Anyone has a suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards
Massimo

Comment: I tried also the code on this page and it's now working as well:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/asset_model_examples.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could try the function TreatAsContent to treat content with code differently than just contentblockbykey. See more info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontent.htm

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.

I tried as well but it's not working. I figured out that the problem is related to the HTML. The script doesn't allow me to insert any content HTML with ".